# screen that is not displayed in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a React-Native app and want to set up navigation.
I created my file with the NavigationContainer and I thought I had done things correctly but I have a problem when changing the screen. I have no actual error in Expo or the bundler but the display of the requested screen is not done, although the header changes. So I feel like I'm missing something in the code. I know I made a mistake, but I need you to help me figure it out and fix it ... Thank you for your time and help.

Navigation :

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Image } from 'react-native'
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
    import { createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack"
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
    import Authentication from '../../Screens/Authentication'
    import Login from '../../Screens/Authentication'
    import Signup from '../../Screens/Authentication'
    import Tools from '../../Screens/Tools'
    import Dashboard from '../../Screens/Dashboard'
    import Settings from '../../Screens/Settings'
    import Scan from '../../Screens/Tools'
    import Ean13 from '../../Screens/Tools'
    import Welcome from '../../Screens/Welcome'
    import i18n from '../../src/i18n'
    
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    function ScreenNavigator() {
      return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Authentication' component = {Authentication}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Login' component = {Login}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Signup' component = {Signup}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Tools' component = {Tools}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Scan' component = {Scan}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Ean13' component = {Ean13}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Dashboard' component = {Dashboard}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Settings' component = {Settings}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = 'Welcome' component = {Welcome}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
      )
    }

 function AppNavigation() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed"
                         tabBarOptions={{activeTintColor: '#F78400'}}>
            <Tab.Screen
              name={i18n.t("app.auth")}
              component={ScreenNavigator}
              options={{
                  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                    return (
                      <Image
                        source={require("../../assets/images/authentication.jpg")}
                        style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                      />
                    );
                  }
              }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name={i18n.t("app.dash")}
              component={Dashboard}
              options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                  return (
                    <Image
                      source={require("../../assets/images/dashboard.png")}
                      style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                    />
                  );
                }
              }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name={i18n.t("app.tools")}
              component={Tools}
              options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                  return (
                    <Image
                      source={require("../../assets/images/tools.png")}
                      style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                    />
                  );
                }
              }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name={i18n.t("app.settings")}
              component={Settings}
              options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                  return (
                    <Image
                      source={require("../../assets/images/settings.png")}
                      style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                    />
                  );
                }
              }}
            />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      )
    }
export default {AppNavigation, ScreenNavigator};
```

Authentication.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, } from 'react-native'
import Login from './Login'
import Signup from './Signup'
import styles from '../../assets/styles'
import i18n from '../../src/i18n'

export default function Authentication({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Signup/>
        <Button title= "Déjà inscrit ? Cliquez ici pour vous identifier"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Alert, Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import styles from '../../assets/styles';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  go = () => {
           const reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
            if (reg.test(this.state.email) === true){
               alert('valid');
           }
           else{
               alert();
           }

  }

  onLogin() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

    Alert.alert('Credentials', `${username} + ${password}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.inputext}>Login Form</Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.username}
          onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
           label='Email'
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
          label='Password'
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <Button
          title={'Login'}
          style={styles.input}
          onPress={this.onLogin.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

At first I'm in the screen Authentication :
[image]

When I click on the bottom button (to go on Login Page) that gives me this : you see in the header the name of the login screen but the display is still Authentication:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your navigation is correct, because the header is changed to login

The problem may come from 'styles.container', that cause the body of login screen has no width/height.

You can measure the body of Login screen by adding onLayout on View to know the width/height, or you can set the width, height of login screen with constants + background color for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. styles.container for now contains : container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
Adding  height: '100%', width: '100%',  backgroundColor: 'blue' doesn't change anything in display.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR =>Check your import paths, you maybe copy pasted a previous import to make a new one and forgot to change the path

I had the same issue. The reason why that happened is because I copy pasted

**import Search from "./Components/Search;**

to make an other import:

**import FilmDetail from "./Components/Search ";**

I forgot to change the "./Components/**Search**" to ./Components/**FilmDetail**

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve code formatting and include an explaination of how this works and why it is solution of the problem described in the question. See [answer].